# Accessing child view controllers of a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am new to iOS, How can I access child view controllers form `UITabBarController` ? Currently, I have the following.

1. RequestTabBarController
2. ActiveRequestsTableViewController
3. RequestViewController

The child view controllers are connected using a `Relationship Segue` in the storyboard. I want to set some properties in child views from `UITabBarController`. How this can be accomplished.

**Storyboard**

[image: storyboard_reference]

Comment: Could you be more specific? "some properties" for which view controller? for the purpose of what?

Comment: Actually, I have an object in `ActiveRequestTableViewController`. I am trying to set that object.

Comment: So what's the problem of setting it in `ActiveRequestTableViewController` itself?

Comment: Actually, I have this data passed through a segue to `RequestTabBarController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might define the following enum for mapping your classes:

```
enum TabType:Int {
    case RequestTabBarController
    case ActiveRequestsTableViewController
    case RequestViewController
}
```

In such way you can have a clean access to your `viewControllers`:

> An array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface.

which you can get directly from your `UITabBarController`, doing so:

```
private weak var tabVc:UITabBarController?
var niceObject:Whatever?
//...//
override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    self.tabVc = segue.destination as? UITabBarController

    if let vc = self.tabVc?.viewControllers?[TabType.RequestTabBarController.rawValue] as? RequestTabBarController {
        vc.doWhatEver(niceObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Acessing the child vcs through `viewControllers` property of `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 1):

From your description above I understand you want to access the children of TabController in order to change some of their properties. If my understanding is correct then you can use the **viewcontrollers** property of UITabBarController to access the children and set the properties.

Comment: Thanks ! That was the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UITabBarController` (for your case it is probably `ManageRequestTabBarController`) and there implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`:

```
public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

This delegate is called when you tap on any tab item and before going to the viewController which is connected with that tabItem.

Here `viewController` is the destination viewController. Use it like this:

```
if viewController is YourDestinationVC {
    let yourDestinationVC = viewController as! YourDestinationVC
    yourDestinationVC.yourCustomValue = someValueYouWantToPass
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand your idea. But this is for when we tap the item. As we know when we come to a tab bar controller there is a default tab bar item pre selected ? how we handle this

Comment: Please explain what is the data you want to pass? How it will impact in your first ViewController?

Comment: The data for now is an object whose properties will be used to construct an API call

Comment: you can set up that data from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate` (from where you can also setup tabbar)

Comment: The issue is, when you create a tab Bar controller you have some default view controller, it cannot be accessed using this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your UI in storyboard you can implement `prepareForSegue` in your `UITabBarController` subclass. It gets called once for every `childViewController`. To distinguish between the different `childViewControllers` you can either use `segueIdentifiers` or check the segues' `destinationViewController`s type (assuming each `childViewController` has a different type).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on the current IOS version.